Allow current location access via my React Native App
I have react native app that displays a responsive website. We have a wrapper built around the app to display this responsive website.
Now the problem is that in the website we have enabled current location access. This works fine when I open the website in mobile browser such as Samsung, Chrome, iPhone etc. However, when I open the app, it doesn't work. The app doesn't have any permission too.
Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

You need to request location permissions from the OS for you app bb
